# Clarification of 90/180 rule

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden

I am  an Indian citizen holding a valid residence permit for work from Sweden. I want to know how the 90/180 rule works for person holding a valid residence permit within a member state. Does this permit allow them to travel within other Schengen countries? If yes, then how can those 90 days be spent over 180 days? E.g. iIf I travel out from Sweden to another Schengen country only for 2 days, and returning back to Sweden (as per the rule, my stay inside Sweden on valid residence permit is not going to count) Does it mean that I was in Schengen only for 2 days? And I still have 88 days left? Is it possible to divide these 88 days over many trips within Schengen while returning back to Sweden after any short trip? Am I allowed to make my second trip after spending 2 months in Sweden as long as I'm not exceeding the 90 days limit?

Comment: Can anybody give me reference if i am allowed to splitt those 90 days over many trips with in other schengen countries not more than one week at a time ,but the only difference  in my case is that am not going to leave schengen just going back to my residence country as stay inside Sweden does not count inside those 90 days. ( becoz coming back to Sweden stop that clock ticking )