# 90/180 rule while holding a swedish residence holder permit

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, france, 90-180-visa-rules, swedish-residents

I am an Indian citizen, holding a valid residence permit from Sweden. I have a confusion about 90/180 rule. For eg if I am planning to travel to France 12/06 to 18/06. It's just a 6 days trip. How long will I have to wait before my next trip within Schengen? Should I wait for 90 days until my next trip or can I make unlimited trip over a period of 90 days not exceeding the limit of 90 days over 180?

Comment: You don't have to wait at all for your next trip, you just have to make sure you don't exceed 90 days in any 180-day period.  In fact, the rule isn't systematically enforced for people with residence permits, so you almost certainly don't need to worry very much about it.  The duplicate question of [your previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/114728/19400) covers this: [90/180 rule while holding a work permit from norway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/114643/19400), as does the same user's [first question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/114633/19400).

Comment: So it means that their is no any limit of trips within 180 days as long as i am not exceeding 90 days limit ? Can i divide those 90 days into Many short trips with In 180 days ?

Comment: Correct. Time you are in Sweden does not count towards your 90 days, but it does count for resetting the clock entirely. Moreover, with the lack of border controls, it would be very difficult for anyone to count your days outside Sweden but elsewhere in Schengen, at least unless you became a target of an investigation for some totally different reason and the police obtained your bank and cellphone records.

Comment: " it does count for resetting the clock " mean time spend in sweden help to stop ticking 90/180 clock ?

Comment: I could not understand the term " 90 days In any 180 ". Does mean 90 days In and 90 days out ? But In my case i dont want to consume my all 90 days limit i one trip. I want to make 3-4 small trips not more than one week at a time over a period of 180 days  while keeping In mind those 90 days limit. Here i am confused how does those 90 days count? does it start from the day i enter other Schengen country and stop when i come back to my residence country and start again when i leave for my next trip? In my mind those 90 days should be the days i spend In other Schengen countries not in sweden ?

Comment: @JasmeenKaurSidhu If you spend 45 days in Norway, or any Schengen state _other than Sweden_ and then 90 days in Sweden, (1) you are legal and (2) you can spend another 90 days in Norway immediately, because the 90/180 will include the 90 Swedish days in the 180, but not in the 90 days allowed.

Comment: If I make only one week trip and come to back to Sweden and stay for 2 month and travel again for one week and come back again and stay for 2-3 month in my residence country.In this case how 90/180 works? Does those 90 days counts straight from the day one I leave Sweden even though I spend only one week in schengen and rest in my residence country ? In this way my time consume should be one week out of those 90 days since I came week to Sweden after short trip, and I don't have to wait for next trip. Please clarify this.